# Issue when pushing numbers to an array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, types

The issue I am having is displayed in the picture. 
I am able to convert the strings into number type using map but when wishing to push to an array of numbers I am unable to. Also I am trying to maintain types but I believe this may be the issue but I am unable to make headway.Maybe I should create another variable and store the newly created number values into that array? Also when console logging I am just getting the single value as a number and not as an array.

```
openValues: string | number[];
```

I hope someone can please help...

````
 getData() {
    this.pricingService.getDailyPricing().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dailyData = data;
      const timeSeries = data['Time Series (Daily)'];
      const dailyDates = Object.keys(timeSeries);
      dailyDates.forEach((parentKey) => {
        const parentValue = timeSeries[parentKey];
        const childKeys = Object.keys(parentValue);
        this.dailyDates = new Date(parentKey);
        childKeys.forEach((childKey) => {
          const keyName = childKey;
          const keyValue = parentValue[childKey];
          this.timeSeriesSeperationMethod(keyName, keyValue);
        });
      });
    });
  }```

The image attached contains the issue.
[![The Image of this issue able to convert to number but unable to push to an array of numbers][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1JA.gif
````

Comment: "when wishing to push to an array of numbers I am unable to" - what does 'unable to' mean? Do you get an error or just an unexpected result? If it's either of those, can you add it into the question?

Comment: I am referring to my ability to push the converted string to a number array.

Comment: Please consider editing the code in the question so as to constitute a [mcve] as desribed in [ask] (and note that images of code are discouraged and should be replaced by actual text-based code).  If you can demonstrate your issue with self-contained code suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) you'll have a much better chance of getting a helpful answer.  Good luck!

Comment: @EdwardSams, you still didn't answer my question though. What does or does not happen when you attempt? Error - show the error message. Unexpected result - tell us what that is.